# Output only characters between [ABC] and [/ABC]

Tags: perl, scripting

```
$ cat somefile.txt
afsdfv
asdf[ABC]dafga
asdfasf
yxcvyxv[/ABC]
asdadf
yv[ABC]sdfb
sdfgadfg
[/ABC]adf
asdf
$ cat somefile.txt | NEEDEDONELINER > output.txt
dafga
asdfasf
yxcvyxv
sdfb
sdfgadfg
$
```

So the "`NEEDEDONELINER`" only outputs the characters between a `[ABC]` and `[/ABC]`.

`[ABC]` could occur several times, and there could be random characters around it.

I only need the random chars between the `[ABC]` and `[/ABC]`.

I don't have time to learn Perl :\

Thank you in anticipiation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you do.
[perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) and then [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

```
m!\Q[ABC]\E\K(.*?)(?=\Q[/ABC]\E)!g;
```

But that doesn't take into account multiline strings - Which your clarification has.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

open my $fh, '<', $ARGV[0];
my $full_file = do { local $/; <$fh> };

say join "\n", $full_file =~ m!
                              \Q[ABC]\E \K
                               (.*?)
                             (?=\Q[/ABC]\E)
                            !gxs;
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
perl -E 'say join qq!\n!, do { local $/; <> } =~ m!\Q[ABC]\E\K(.*?)(?=\Q[/ABC]\E)!gs' somefile.txt > output.txt
```

But what if your files are huge? just reading them into memory won't do. You'll have to figure that one out yourself, though.

Answer (score 1):

I see a totally useless use of cat.

```
perl -le '$/="";$_=<>;print$2while/\[(ABC\])(.*?)\[\/\1/gs' <file.txt
```

(Oh this some nice golfing ;-)

Comment: Any spaces would only make it harder to reach the goal of being a "one-liner" - given the command is also 60 chars, the PS1 prompt and filename will in many cases already exceed one line in the terminal window of 80.

Answer (score 0):

FIX: 
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=NHep1FYp

Answer (score 0):

A very similar question was asked on the Fedora mailing list a couple of days ago. Here's the answer I gave there (which will need some rather obvious editing):

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl

 use strict;
 use warnings;

 while (<>) {
   if (m|\[XYZ]| .. m|\[/XYZ]|) {
     next if m|\[/?XYZ]|;
     print;
   }
 }
```